# Looking for a canonical example of this overflow problem

Tags: c, overflow

This came up in an interview recently (the concept) and I was discussing it with a friend today.  Here's the idea:

Suppose you are calculating the dot product of a three-dimensional vector.  Simple function would be "return (x1*x2)+(y1*y2)+(z1*z2)".

However, if the first and second term are large positive numbers, they could overflow even if they answer is within the acceptable range.  For example, let's say the integer limit is 128.  100 + 100 - 80 = 120, but if you do the first two additions first you'll overflow.

In a university class this came up on a C assignment where we were calculating something that we'd probably done a thousand times before but had never paid attention to overflow (this was the part when we were learning about writing sanitary code), like taking an average or something of the sort.

Anyone have any idea in what context this could have happened?  I know it was some situation where you had to use comparisons either before or instead of addition/subtraction to avoid this overflow

Comment: You are sure that the products don't overflow?

Comment: This is just an example of what I'm talking about.  I know there's a "better" example of it out there; trying to figure out what it is.  In my example, yes, let's assume the products don't overflow.

Comment: you want example?  calculatiog angle between "long" vectors ?

Comment: This is hopeless vague; there are many "canonical" examples and there's no way to know which one you have (or rather no longer have) in mind ... although the answer from James is somewhat likely.

Comment: In your particular case, when you just add the products, if the final result should be in range, then even in case of overflows it will be the same, considering 2's complement arithmetics. Also, C compiler won't even let you check for possible overflow, because it's considered UB (and thus your checks will be optimized out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary search is a classic example. Many many implementations do a computation that's basically finding the midpoint of two indices:
    (high + low) / 2
but if high and low are each near Integer.MAX_VALUE or the equivalent for your language, high+low overflows before the divide can happen, and your answer is wrong:

http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Easy fix is in that case to do:
    high/2 + low/2 
instead, which doesn't overflow but it's an almost universal bug in implementations of binary search, and it's the very first thing to pop into mind when someone talks about an overflow in a computation that should result in a non-overflowing value.

Comment: Hm, your fix isn't too convincing as such. If I'd have both `high` and `low` an odd number I wouldn't get the right answer. E.g if `low` is `1` and high is `3`, this gives me `1`, whereas `(low + high)/2` is `2`. Even worse, when both values are equal to `2x+1`, you'd fall one below that value to `2x`.

Comment: Also low + (high-low)/2 works for binary search, but not for general averaging because high-low can overflow in the general case.